# Pyspark: Split Spark Dataframe string column and loop the string list to find the matched string into multiple columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rdd

The data I meet is like this:

req_id         dsp_price_style

```
0   "1000:10,1001:100,1002:5,1003:7" 
1   "1002:5,1000:100,1001:15,1003:6"
```

the value format of the field 'dsp_price_style' is dsp_id_0:price_0,dsp_id_1:price_1,.....,dsp_id_n:price_n while they are not sorted between dsp_id, I only need the data which dsp_id is '1000' and dsp_id is '1001' and its price, and add these 4 data as new column using pyspark.

req_id   dsp_0    price_0    dsp_1    price_1

```
0     "1000"     "10"     "1001"    "100"   
1     "1000"    "100"     "1001"     "15"
```

How to implement this function with best performance in pyspark?

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an approach here.

```
data = [
    [0,"1000:10,1001:100,1002:5,1003:7"],
    [1,"1002:5,1000:100,1001:15,1003:6"]
]

data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['req_id', 'dsp_price_style'])

# the function to split
def split_dsp_price(row):
    ls_x = row.dsp_price_style.split(sep=',')
    return [row.req_id] + reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [k.split(sep=':') for k in ls_x if k[:4] in ['1000', '1001']])

fnl_data_rdd = data_sdf.rdd.map(lambda r: split_dsp_price(r))

fnl_data_rdd.take(2)

# [[0, '1000', '10', '1001', '100'], [1, '1000', '100', '1001', '15']]
```

This can further be converted to a `DataFrame` or further processed.